# Android in-app purchase static response testing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm developing application that is using one in-app purchase product. I decided to use static response testing as adviced [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) but I have problem with `android.test.purchased`. My in-app mechanics is based on [Selling In-app Products](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) and `TrivialDrive` example. Before using static responses I was checking if basic things are working with quering my inventory for product price (my app has one product created in Developer Console) and it worked well. Then I tried to make first test purchase using `android.test.purchased`, it seemed to work. But when I tried to query inventory after that, I got error:
 
`Problem with inventory query: IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)` 
After that every attempt to use inventory was resulting in this error. Even checking price of real product (which worked earlier) was not successful. The problem could be fixed with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22088718/4734356), but it is far from solving the problem. Consuming purchase is not the solution if I want to test my app's in-app handling flow without having to upload it and waiting for update every time I want to change/fix something. And this is what's left for me without properly working static responses. The author of the answer also mentioned that static responses are broken, but it's hard to believe for me that problem this big could not be solved for that long.

Can someone help me in this matter?

Comment: follow this link; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600664/android-in-app-purchase-signature-verification-failed

Comment: @prakash Thanks for the comment. Although I checked top comment in this link and I was not satisfied with it, I gave a better look to the other comments. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23007943/4734356) answer led me to to the good workaround.