# In app billing on Android shows error : 1003 : Purchase signature verification failed

Tags: android, in-app-billing, signature

I am trying to verify whether product is purchased or not from store.

For that I have used the below code :

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

And call back is as mentioned below :

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        **if (result.isFailure()) { // This fails in our case**
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

    }
};
```

But every time I am getting same error as shown in below attached screen.

[image]

I have tried with below mentioned steps but failed to get success.

- "base64EncodedPublicKey" verified from our google play account where app is launched in alpha testing mode
- Application is signed with release keystore
- "base64EncodedPublicKey" - copied to notepad first and then copy to java file (read somewhere in blogs for this solution) , but that has not work for me.

Can anybody suggest for the same. Please let me know if I need to add something in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution :)

There was an issue with registering a broadcast receiver.

Plese find below code of **startSetup** method which is registering broadcast receiver that was missing from the following snippet.

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
  if (!result.isSuccess()) {
     // Oh noes, there was a problem.
     Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
  }  mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(MainActivity.this);
            IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);
     // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!   }});
```

Comment: What do you mean by ~"**issue with registering a broadcast receiver**"?  What was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to purchase **android.test.purchased** or another item? If you are using android.test.purchased, check this answer, it should answer your question: [Android in app purchase: Signature verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600664/android-in-app-purchase-signature-verification-failed)

Comment: No we are not using "android.test.purchased".