# Google IAP response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

My goal here is to implement an In-app purchase in my app and also to check if Users owns an item as each app launch. Below is what I have tried so far and the issue I am seeing.

This is the code in my main `LAUNCHER` Activity. I am using **android.test.purchased** as my ITEM_SKU (is this a problem?) to test the in-app purchase locally. It did work once initially and since them I am getting this error inside `onQueryInventoryFinished`: **Failed to query inventory: IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)**

```
// Does the user have the premium upgrade?
boolean mIsaddFree = false;
private AdView adView;

private static final String TAG = "com.example.inappbilling";
IabHelper mHelper;
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
        }

    }
};


IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        mLog.printToLog(className + " -> " + MethodName.methodName() + ": Query inventory finished.");
        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            mLog.printToLog(className + " -> " + MethodName.methodName() + "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
        } else {


            if (inventory.hasPurchase(ITEM_SKU)) {mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),mConsumeFinishedListener);
            } else {
            }

        }

        // Do we have the addFree upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
        mIsaddFree = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));

    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {


                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };

/**
 * Verifies the developer payload of a purchase.
 */
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
    return true;
}

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

private void setupIAB() {
    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgQEbYA2GEYavRb1oZz9aMyn86Wj09NCqFRbD936uKLJHKSDFdsfsdfklndfHKJHJKAHFKJDSFskdsfkjnsdfjkKJNJKSDF9ZclxWM3EuZTMM3kWDUfOnS0+u8c/Uq727cLBRqnRJy5pfWFZtPqXwAN4yaeCgxGka6eofn0jj7RxPEFJZLkFw2Ijvxl2uMIHSlxIvl+6ZwMtOKJHSDKJFHNDSllkadndfkasdlkasdlkasBOaBLKWFYY2to8g3aRx1HVTxLSi9Ms3KPMM3uPbbElCbKoIiqcNwIDAQAB";

    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    mLog.printToLog(className + " -> " + MethodName.methodName() + ": Creating IAB helper.");
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(!Constants.C_PRODUCTION_MODE);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           return;
                                       } else {
                                           mLog.printToLog(className + " -> " + MethodName.methodName() + ": Passed, result.isSuccess() = TRUE");


                                           // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                                           if (mHelper == null) return;

                                           // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
                                           mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
                                       }
                                   }
                               });


}


/**
 * Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
 */
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase adFreePurchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
        mIsaddFree = (adFreePurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(adFreePurchase));


    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupIAB();
}
```

I have changed the function `verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey,
                                         String signedData, String signature)` in `Security.java` as per [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534210/in-app-billing-not-working-after-update-google-store)

Comment: Which buildType are u using? You only can get items from a PlayStore signed apk, not debug one

Comment: Buildtype i DEBUG currently but I do not have items in the Play Store. I am developing a new app. Is there a problem using *android.test.purchased* as the SKU?

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip verification process or send true from verification signature method during testing this happen because once you purchase using test id which is not signed so that you get this error