# Setting subscription to inactive in google playstore

Tags: android, billing, subscriptions

While developing an android app I added two test subscriptions in the google play console with some fictional prices. Now the app is productive and the test subscription prices are displayed to the users inside the playstore:

[image]

I tried to deactivate the test subscription in the play console but the button for this is inactive:

[image]
*(*the text says that an active subscription could not be deactivated at any time.)*

Can anybody help me to get rid of the not needed subscriptions?

-Thanks in advance, Dirk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In App billing not working after update - Google Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534210/in-app-billing-not-working-after-update-google-store)

Comment: This sounds more like a question for the Google Play Support, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree with @DavidStockinger, the question appears to have nothing to do with programming and is off-topic IMHO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: And the question is still not closed!

Comment: 2019 and still no option? Even though I only have my app in alpha I can't remove the subscription.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After contacting google support I got the following response:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.
>
> As you've noticed, no subscription can be deactivated once created. 
>   You can hide your current subscriptions by removing reference to them
>   in the code, but the Play Store Listing for your app will always
>   include the prices of such subscriptions because they exist in the
>   Play Console.  This is working as intended.  It is recommended that
>   you never use 'fictional' (as you put it) prices when testing your
>   app's functionality.
>
> The only way around this would be to start over with a new app and
>   package name, taking care not to create any fictional subscription
>   items.

Not the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: this is really so stupid from google. you need to publish a new version of your app to remove old subscriptions and have new ones.

Comment: Absolute stupidity of Google Play!! A single technical mistake on your developer console can cost you so much in your app listing, permanently. This is not what we pay 30% to Google for!! Its really so pleasure to work with Apple App Store.

Comment: The best you can do is edit all of your subscriptions' prices to be really low. (I think the minimum is 50 cents) That way, your playstore listing looks less scary to users.

Comment: I personally recommend the IAPHUB (I am a user) to handle the skus.

Answer (score 2):

Do not waste your time trying method using google play developer api mentioned by **rkunboxed**, it doesn't work.

You will get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Deleting a published subscription is not allowed.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

For more details, see:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts?authuser=2